# How to remove registered client scripts

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` with some key. It is not allowing me to add another scripts from code behind. So I am thinking to remove all these kind of scripts before registering new one. But I can't find anyway to clear it.

My situation is I have timer on my page and its causing post back. At each post back I want to invoke JS function. It works for first time but on timer post back, it doesn't.

This is how I am registering it

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction" + random, "Notify(\"" + notificationText + "\", null, null,\"danger\");", true);
```

random is GUID

Comment: add your code please

Comment: @WinterMute updated code

Comment: sorry, but you should really add some details, for example where you call ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and also how do you trigger the postback, it is an async ajax post?